# Gigabyte R9 280x blue screens - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod, amd-radeon

I'm building a new mining rig right now and I just installed Windows 7 x64 Home Premium on the Hard Drive.

I installed the Chipset Driver, the USB Controller Driver, and the LAN Driver. That is everything installed on the computer.

I didn't experience any problems, until I installed the [13.11 Beta v9.5 Drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx) from AMD and restarted the computer to activate the drivers.

That installer installed two possible drivers for me to choose from besides the default one:

[image]

I can select and install either of them. When I restart my computer, I can log in normally and use the computer until it looks like the driver gets stuck in a loop and crashes the computer and I get a blue screen.

If I switch back to using the default VGA drivers that come with windows and I experience no blue screens at all.

Here is the error report from the blue screen:

> Problem signature:
>    Problem Event Name:  BlueScreen
>    OS Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3
>    Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:
>    BCCode: 100000ea
>    BCP1: FFFFFA8005BB9B60
>    BCP2: 0000000000000000
>    BCP3: 0000000000000000
>    BCP4: 0000000000000000
>    OS Version: 6_1_7600
>    Service Pack: 0_0
>    Product: 768_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>    C:\Windows\Minidump\121113-22666-01.dmp
>    C:\Users\Kuplack\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-40809-0.sysdata.xml
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement >offline:
>    C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

**Hardware**

---

- CPU: [AMD Athlon X3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103911)
- Motherboard: [ASUS Crosshair V Formula-Z](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131876)
- Video Card: [Gigabyte R9 280X 3GB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125490)
- RAM: 1 stick of 4GB 1600 Mhz
- Hard Drive: 1TB

What can I do to fix this? Is there a more stable driver out there? Is something wrong with my video card or Windows version?

If it makes a difference the reason I'm using Windows is because I spent 3 days trying to work out similar problems I was having in Xubuntu and Ubuntu. I tried 32-bit, 64-bit, 13.10, and 12.04 LTS for both distros and always had problems. So I decided to switch to Windows and I'm still having problems.

**Update:** For now I think I'm going to try out an older driver, maybe 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OS Version: 6_1_7600` means you still use the Windows 7 RTM. The newer AMD drivers require the Sp1. So [install the Sp1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1) and try the new drivers again.